# Multithread buffer C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, buffer

I have a buffer to read data from socket, but i have a problem, more that 3 threads wants to access to him, how can i create multithread buffer for them?

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of rules do you want to impose. Serialise reading? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what the threads expect to get from the socket. It's unlikely that it's okay for the data from the socket to get scrambled up between the three thread's reads, so you need some synchronization on a scale larger than just making sure that each thread can read bytes out of the socket without interfering with the other threads' ability to do the same.

So how are the threads supposed to be synchronized? Are they independently pulling records out of the socket? Are they all supposed to be reading all data? Something else?

If they're independently pulling records from the socket you should simply have one thread read the records from the socket, construct some kind of record object, and place those objects in a thread-safe queue for the 3 threads to access.

If the threads are all supposed to read the same data then you have a buffer where each thread registers with the buffer and the buffer keeps track of where every reader is. The buffer would then keep data until all threads had read it, and once the all had it would erase the data and fill that space up with more data from the socket.